# Get the distance between two CGPoints in a UIImageView nested in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, distance, cgpoint

```
CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.size.width;
CGRect visibleRect;
    visibleRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset;
    visibleRect.size = imageView.frame.size;
    CGPoint midPoint = CGPointMake(visibleRect.origin.x + visibleRect.size.width / 2, visibleRect.origin.y + visibleRect.size.height / 2);
CGPoint place = CGPointMake(class.xValue, class.yValue);
```

xValue and yValue being 'int's declared in the class.

```
-(int)distanceFrom:(CGPoint)point1 to:(CGPoint)point2{
CGFloat xDist = ((point2.x) - (point1.x));
CGFloat yDist = ((point2.y) - (point1.y));
return (sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)));
}
```

The problem is that once I change the zoomScale by scrolling in the app and recall the method the numbers change drastically (~1000 pixels). How to I take into account for the zoomScale? Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

when you are zooming in, the result from distance method is multiplied by `zoomScale` of the scroll view. If you want get actual distance, try dividing the distance by `zoomScale` of the scroll view.

Comment: did it work? It it worked, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left. thanks